# Relationship between optimal value and optimal point for strongly convex and smooth function

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For a $\mu$ strong convex and $L$ smooth function $f:\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$, assume its unique global optimal point is $x^*$.

Intuitively, if our current $x$ is very close to $x^*$, then the current function value should also be close to $f(x^*)$. And conversely, if our current function value is very close to $f(x^*)$, our current $x$ should also be close to $x^*$. I am wondering that is this intuition correct? If it is, can we prove it?

For a possible formal expression of this intuition, can we use $||x-x^*||_2$ to control $|f(x) - f(x^*)|$? And can we use $|f(x) - f(x^*)|$ to control $||x-x^*||_2$?

Comment: Yes, just use standard subgradient inequalities (with $f'(x^*)=0$): $L$-smoothness: $$f(y)\leq f(x) + f'(x)^{\top}(y-x) + \frac{L}{2}||y-x||^2 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ and $\mu$-strong convexity: $$f(y)\geq f(x) + f'(x)^{\top}(y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2}||y-x||^2 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ Here I am assuming "optimal" means "minimum."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But these relationship is not very clear. For example, if $||x-x^*||_2$ is 0.01, those inequalities can not tell us what is the upper bound of $|f(x)-f(x^*)|$ and vice versa.

Comment: The inequalities, with the substitution in my comment, directly tell us all of the desired bounds, including the $0.01$ question and the vice versa question.  Directly in one line. Here I am assuming $x^*$ is a global minimum of $f$.

Comment: Oh, yes! You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives detail on my comments: We have by standard subgradient inequalities:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $L$-smooth then:
$$ f(y)\leq f(x) + f'(x)^{\top}(y-x) + \frac{L}{2}||y-x||^2 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-strongly convex then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $f'(x)\in \partial f(x)$:
$$ f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)^{\top}(y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2}||y-x||^2 \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

---

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is both $L$-smooth and $\mu$-strongly convex, and if $x^*$ is a global min of $f$, then $f'(x^*)=0$ and so we obtain

\begin{align}
f(y)\leq f(x^*) + \frac{L}{2}||y-x^*||^2 \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\\
f(y)\geq f(x^*) + \frac{\mu}{2}||y-x^*||^2 \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

Since $f(y)\geq f(x^*)$ for all $y$, we have $f(y)-f(x^*)=|f(y)-f(x^*)|$ and so the above two inequalities can be written
$$ \frac{\mu}{2}||y-x^*||^2\leq |f(y)-f(x^*)|\leq \frac{L}{2}||y-x^*||^2 \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
From this it also follows that $L\geq \mu$.